# Are scalar fields invariant under unitary operators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Is this correct?  Are scalar fields defined as being invariant under $U^{\dagger}U$ transformations?  If so, is this transformation also called the trivial transformation?  Thanks for any help or comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on the "type" of scalar field you're referring to.

For example, in quantum field theory, we assume that there exists some unitary action of the Lorentz group $\mathrm{SO}(3,1)$ acting on fields $\phi$ given by
$$
  \phi(x) \longrightarrow U(\Lambda)\phi(x) U(\Lambda)^{-1}
$$
We say that the field $\phi$ is a scalar with respect to this representation (aka a **Lorentz scalar**) provided
$$
  U(\Lambda)\phi(x)U(\Lambda)^{-1} = \phi(\Lambda^{-1} x)
$$
for all $\Lambda\in\mathrm{SO}(3,1)$.  Notice that this does not mean that $\phi$ is invariant under all unitary transformations on the Hilbert space.  It means that it transforms in a particular way under the family of unitary transformations parameterized by the Lorentz group defined above.

Comment: Thanks for noting it does not mean $\phi$ is invariant under all unitary transformations...  and for your very detailed final statement.  That is good information, thanks joshphysics

Comment: @curiousGeorge119 Sure thing.